# Expected behaviour of shm_unlink?

Tags: c++, ipc, shared-memory

Does `shm_unlink` store a reference count to determine when to delete the file?

I ask because I have the following:

Writer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

void Sleep(int ms)
{
    usleep(ms * 1000);
}

int main()
{
    int fd = shm_open("/Test", O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR, 0600);
    if (fd != -1)
    {
        ftruncate(fd, 512);
        void *ptr = mmap(0, 512, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
        if (ptr)
        {
            sprintf((char*)ptr, "hello");
            std::cout<<"Written & Sleeping\n";
            Sleep(10000);
            munmap(ptr, 512);
        }
        close(fd);
        shm_unlink("/Test");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Reader:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

void Sleep(int ms)
{
    usleep(ms * 1000);
}

int main()
{
    int fd = shm_open("/Test", O_RDWR, 0600);
    if (fd != -1)
    {
        ftruncate(fd, 512);
        void *ptr = mmap(0, 512, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
        if (ptr)
        {
            printf("Read: %s\n", (char*)ptr);
            munmap(ptr, 512);
        }
        close(fd);
        shm_unlink("/Test");
    }

    Sleep(1000);

    fd = shm_open("/Test", O_RDWR, 0600);
    if (fd != -1)
    {
        ftruncate(fd, 512);
        void *ptr = mmap(0, 512, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
        if (ptr)
        {
            printf("Read: %s\n", (char*)ptr);
            munmap(ptr, 512);
        }
        close(fd);
        shm_unlink("/Test");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The writer maps the memory just fine. It shows up in `/dev/shm` as `Test` which is expected. The reader can also map it successfully.

However, the reader is only able to memory map the file ONCE. After closing it the first time, it is immediately deleted and the second call to `shm_open` fails.

Is this the expected behaviour? Is `shm_unlink` supposed to delete the file even if the writer has it open? It deletes it as soon as the reader calls `shm_unlink`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior. From the manual page:

> The `shm_unlink()` function disassociates the shared memory object specified by `name` from that name.

It's exactly like `unlink()` on normal files in that regard.

If you don't want to do that, just `close()` the file descriptor. No other cleanup is necessary.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the response. If I close the file descriptor, will the last process that exists delete the file?

Comment: No. Only `shm_unlink()` will do that.